# Google Apps Script setFormula() in sheet cell encounters "#REF!" issue by using function doGet(e)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Sheet cell can successfully show the result of the formula I setup from myFunction() but failed when I input variable by using doGet(e) {  }. It shows "#REF!" in the cell and "unresolved sheet name xx".

In this function, setFormula() can successfully show the result in sheet cell.

```
function myFunction() {
var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxgid=0");
var sheet1 = ss1.getSheetByName("Sheet1");  
var sheet;
sheet = 6;
var sheet = sheet.toString();
sheet1.getRange(6,9).setFormula(sheet + '!B1');
}
```

Later on, I followed the syndax of setFormula to setup as below, but somehow it not work. It shows "#REF!" in sheet cell.

```
function doGet(e) {

var shopname = e.parameter.shop1;    
var shopname = shopname.toString();
var row = sheet.activate().getLastRow();
sheet.activate().getRange(row,9).setFormula( shopname + '!B1');

//  sheet.activate().getRange(row,9).setFormula("'" + shopname + "'!" + "B1");
//    sheet1.getRange(6,9).setFormula("'" + sheet + "'!" + "B1");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `sheet` is not defined within the function `doGet()`

- If you want to make it accessible by both `myFunction` and `doGet` - you need to make it a **global** variable
- However, currently `sheet` is a value (`6`) rather than a sheet object
- What you probably want to do is to write the data in `sheet1`?

**A sample to do so:**

```js
var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
var sheet1 = ss1.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); 

function myFunction() { 
  var sheet;
  sheet = 6;
  sheet1.getRange(6,9).setFormula(sheet + '!B1');
}


function doGet(e) {
  
  var shopname = e.parameter.shop1;    
  var shopname = shopname.toString();
  var row = sheet1.getLastRow();
  sheet1.getRange(row,9).setFormula( shopname + '!B1');
}
```

Note: You do not need to `activate()` a sheet or range to access it

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, both functions are separate to 2 files. My plan is to write by doGet(e) function. The myFunction is just to pre-test. Once it works, then I put to doGet(e) for test.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to incorporate the line `sheet1.getRange(6,9).setFormula(sheet + '!B1');` into `doGet()`? Everything else is already set-up in a way that `doGet()` will work without `myFunction()`.

Comment: I've modified my problem statement to make it more clear.

Comment: `#REF!` means that there is no sheet with the name contained in the variable `shopname`. What is the value you are passing as parameter `shop1` when you call the WebApp? What is the name of the sheet you want to set into `getRange(row,9)`?

Comment: It works now. I believe that's because the parameter "shopname" might be empty.